# cURL to accss a different user page after login

Tags: php, curl

How do we use cURL (or simple_html_dom.php) to get the contents of a different page once a user has automatically logged in (by cURL) ?

In a senario,

```
http://example.com/login
```

a user automatically logs in with cURL as below. `example.com` then redirects to a page `example.com/dashboard` .

However, I would like to go to a different page, such as `example.com/history` to access the same user's history page through cURL.

I have the following code and have reached the user's dashboard. I am unable to get the user's history page.

So far, this is what I have :

```
$html = file_get_html('http://example.com/login');


// login in virootols
$cookie="cookie.txt"; 
$postdata = "username=".$username.
        "&password=".$password;

$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/validate'); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://example.com/login'); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_exec ($ch); 


// the script here is not executing
$html = file_get_html('http://example.com/history');
echo $html;
```

** UPDATE **

@ h2ooooooo

I added

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

and

```
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 

$html = str_get_html($result);  

echo $html; die;
```

and I am getting `http://example.com/history` in the body of the browser.

That is what you were saying right ?

Comment: Try using file_get_contents. Haven't heard of file_get_html.

Comment: You also have a syntax error when defining `CURLOPT_REFERER`

Comment: @IanBrindley Corrected it

Comment: Get the content with regular cURL (with `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` set to `true`) and use `str_get_html($curlExecResult)` instead. As long as you use the same cookie jar on the two different cURL calls, you'd be logged in.

Comment: @noia_0328 I am using this http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ . It seemed to make it easier to extract the required elements.

Answer (score 0):

To update what I wrote in the comments you need to use regular cURL to make the call (and `CURLOPT_RETURNTRASNFER` being true). Make sure you use the same `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` in the two calls to make sure that our login session is saved.

Right now you're first calling `/login` without any parameters, and then you call `/validate` with your login data. You need to first call `/login` with your credentials, and *then* call `/validate`.

Something like this should work:

```
<?php

$cookie = "cookie.txt"; 

$postdata = "username=".$username.
    "&password=".$password;

$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://example.com/login', 
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE, 
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6", 
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60, 
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1, 
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $cookie, 
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postdata, 
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1, 
    CURLOPT_POST => 1, 
));

// Log in
curl_exec ($ch);

// Get validation page
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://example.com/validate',
    CURLOPT_HTTPGET => 1,
));
$html = curl_exec($ch);

$html = str_get_html('http://example.com/history');
print_r($html);
```

Comment: Doing print_r, I get the structure of an object http://pastebin.com/nGYb5XtT . I want to  manipulate table and its contents. How do get the table and its contents from there ?

Comment: @maan81 `$html` is a simple html object, so you can run your typical methods on it such as `$html->find('table')[0]->plaintext`.

Comment: I am not getting a blank screen when I do so. even `print_r($html->find('body')[0]->plaintext);` returns a blank screen.

Comment: @maan81 If you get a blank screen it's because you're getting an error and have `error_reporting` turned off. Check your log files. Please note that your passwords are in your hosted git project.